# user_hometown permission is not working while facebook login in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In facebook login i set permission of "user_hometown" like below but it is not work working. Can anyone tell me what to do in this

```
LoginButton  loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);


    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_hometown"));

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code

            requestUserProfile(loginResult);
            Log.e("facebooksucess", loginResult.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.e("facebook", "fgh");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.e("facebookerror", exception.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: is facebook approved your user_hometown permission request?

Comment: @Nas in approve list i only see the public_profile permission

Comment: then you have to submit user_hometown permission request to facebook review

Comment: mean i have to add permission at developer.facebook.com in app review tab @Nas

Comment: yes check here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_hometown

Comment: Thank you so much i just add it, How much time it take for verification?

Comment: as per facebook it take max 5 working days. but it wont take that much time. they reviewed in couple of days

Comment: Thanks... I have one more question Regarding background service. Can i run my task in background if app is completely close? @Nas

Comment: you can implement by extending service in your class. If you want anything more ask as a separate question.